# TypeError: express is not a function -

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

## Express code  "const app = express()" does not work!!

** Hi, I have some problem here! My console return this error, but i follow the best way! please someone
give me a light.

server.js archive:

````
import * as express from "express";
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
//inciando o app
const app = express();

//iniciando o banco de dados
mongoose.connection('mongodb://localhost:27017/program01', {useNewUrlParser: true});

//primeira rota
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('Hello World')
})

app.listen(3000)


==============================
console: 

*[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
(node:12020) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
(node:8472) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///C:/Users/USUARIO/Documents/Project%20Web/program01/server.js:4
const app = express();
            ^

TypeError: express is not a function
    at file:///C:/Users/USUARIO/Documents/Project%20Web/program01/server.js:4:13        
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:137:37)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:179:24)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...* ```


another's archives :
**node_modules**
**package.json**
**package-lock.json**
**yarn-error.log**
````

Answer (score 15):

You need to use a default import for `express`, i.e.

```
import express from 'express';
```

instead of

```
import * as express from 'express';
```

Comment: I tried this before.  console said ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: What is the version of `node.js` you are using ? Find out with `node -v`

Comment: Node : v12.18.1

Answer (score 3):

add to tsconfig.json

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

and use import like this

```
import express from 'express'
```

it works for my

```
ts-node-esm src/server.ts
```

or

```
node --loader=ts-node/esm --inspect src/server.ts
```

Answer (score 2):

import is an ES6 feature, it hasn't yet been fully supported by Node.js
you should use **require**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
```

Comment: console said "ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Answer (score -1):

Got the same, I used require instead if import. And don't forget to write
require, like this:

```
const express = require('express');
```

Then you can check it in the console.

Comment: This is identical to [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62522204/6243352). Please upvote that rather than adding a redundant answer.